# WordPress 403 errors when using cart

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce

I am losing customers and money every day due to this issue. I have tried htaccess rewrites and folder persmission changes. I have tried everything under the sun. Please help me get rid of this issue. Each time my customers click Add To card on the WordProess/WooCommerce site, I get these errors.

`POST https://www.example.com/wc?-ajax=update_order_review 403 ()`

`POST https://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 403 ()`

I don't care if you give me some HTACCESS file or something that unlocks the folders to the entire planet, please help me fix these errors or I will lose all my customers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. For me it was caused by ModSecurity. I fixed it by turnig ModSecurity off. I logged in to cPanel, clicked on "ModSecurity" and turned it off there for my domain. I don't know if it helps on your case, but that's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this in the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does not work for multisite Wordpress hosting environment

Comment: yes, but how can you use this solution and not risk an attack?